# com.oracle.weblogic.lifecycle.core.PartitionLCMService error

Tags: weblogic

I am getting PartitionLCMService error:

```
Unable to perform operation: resolve on com.oracle.weblogic.lifecycle.core.PartitionLCMService

        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Collector.throwIfErrors(Collector.java:89)

        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:250)

        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:358)

        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)

        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:305)

        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

Caused By: java.lang.NullPointerException

        at javassist.util.proxy.SecurityActions.setAccessible(SecurityActions.java:103)

        at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass3(DefineClassHelper.java:151)

        at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass2(DefineClassHelper.java:134)

        at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass(DefineClassHelper.java:95)

        at javassist.util.proxy.FactoryHelper.toClass(FactoryHelper.java:131)

        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

while trying to setup Weblogic Server when I create a new directory to store the domain and start the server with the `%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe` `weblogic.Server` command. Any help is appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: how did you create your domain and start your server ?

Answer (score 0):

it was the jdk version. When set up with jdk 1.8, no errors.

Comment: What version were you using before? I'm getting this with JDK 11